# Sound card not recognized, at times

Tags: sound

I have a massive issue with my laptop. The sound card is not recognized **at times**. I am on 16.04 and basically it works very well at times and not at all the rest of the times.

I would understand if it did no work at all but this intermittent behaviour sounds riduculous to me. It is still a computer isn't it?

I have tried mitigating the porblem editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and adding the following entry:

```
modprobe snd-hda-intel model=acer # I have an acer, yes!
```

but I had no luck with it.

Any idea?

Comment: It could be the (sound) device is starting to fail, and the problem could get worse until it doesn't work anytime. I would suggest doing a inspection of the hardware looking for any clues....  though if a software configuration issue my 2c is worthless....

Comment: @guiverc could be but I doubt it ... the computer is new and in fact it never worked untill I added the entry above in the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf. After I added that I could at least get it to work at times so I think it's an config thing. Plus I have read other people have that problem with this laptop.